# Xor encryption in C?

Tags: c, encryption, xor

I tried to learn XOR in C and I found [this example](https://github.com/KyleBanks/XOREncryption/blob/master/C/main.c) on github.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {
    char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char baseStr[] = "kylewbanks.com";
    
    char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted);
    printf("Encrypted:%s\n", encrypted);
    
    char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted:%s\n", decrypted);
}
```

Can you explain me this statement?

```
output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
```

PS: If I change the statement in char baseStr[] the output is wrong, why? For example if the value of baseStr is Test the output will be:

```
Encrypted: *?�
Decrypted:Test�&
```

## EDIT

If anyone wanted a working version of this program, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char*, char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char message[500];
    char key[50];

    printf("Enter the message: ");
    fgets(message, 500, stdin);
    message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    fgets(key, 50, stdin);
    key[strcspn(key, "\n")] = 0;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(key); ++i)
        key[i] = toupper (key[i]);

    putchar('\n');

    char encryptedMessage[strlen(message) + 1];
    memset(encryptedMessage, '\0', sizeof(encryptedMessage));
    encryptDecrypt(message, encryptedMessage, key);
    printf("Encrypted message: %s\n", encryptedMessage);

    char decryptedMessage[strlen(message) + 1];
    memset(decryptedMessage, '\0', sizeof(decryptedMessage));
    encryptDecrypt(encryptedMessage, decryptedMessage, key);
    printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decryptedMessage);

    return 0;
}

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output, char *key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); ++i)
        output[i] = input [i] ^ key [i % strlen(key)];
}
```

Comment: A well-formed C string has a zero byte at the end known as the NUL terminator. So the program doesn't work correctly regardless of what's in `baseStr`. You got lucky with the original string and unlucky with `Test`. To fix it, the size of the `encrypted` and `decrypted` arrays need to be larger by one byte, and the `encryptDecrypt` function needs to put the NUL terminator at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it apart, piece by piece:

1. `(sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))` This is the length of the `key` array.  In your case it is `3`.  Note, `sizeof(char)` is redundant and can be omitted.
2. `key[i % 3]` This bounds the index of `key` to `0`, `1`, or `2`, thus not accessing memory outside the `key` array.
3. `output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % 3]`; You're XORing each `char`acter in the `input` with the `key` and assigning it to the `output`.

Note, if you want to print `encrypted` and `decrypted` you should define them like this:

```
char encrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1] = {'\0'};
char decrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1] = {'\0'};
```

**EDIT**

According to [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109), *You aren't allowed to provide initializers when declaring a VLA*.  As such, you should perform (for example) the following:

```
memset(encrypted, '\0', sizeof(encrypted));
memset(decrypted, '\0', sizeof(decrypted));
```

Comment: You aren't allowed to provide initializers when declaring a VLA.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the insight.

Comment: If i write char encrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1] = {'\0'}; i get this error

test.c:16:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
     char encrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1] = {'\0'};
     ^~~~
test.c:16:44: warning: excess elements in array initializer
     char encrypted[strlen(baseStr) + 1] = {'\0'};

Comment: @link23 Yup, you need to remove the `= {'\0'}` from the array declarations. Initializers aren't allowed with variable length arrays (VLA). And you either need to use the `memset` function as suggested in this answer, or use `output[len] = '\0';` as suggested in Schwern's answer.

Comment: @link23 In C, strings are characters arrays with a special character marking the end, `'\0'`.  This is how `strlen` and friends determine the length of a string without explicitly being told.

Answer (score 2):

> PS: If I change the statement in char baseStr[] the output is wrong, why? For example if the value of baseStr is Test the output will be:
>
> ```
> Encrypted: *?�
> Decrypted:Test�&
> ```

This is because `encryptDecrypt` is using `strlen` to determine the end of the "string". `strlen` relies on reading a null byte to determine the end of the string. When encrypting you have a null terminated string. But the encryption does not produce a null terminated string, it produces a stream of bytes which it does not null terminate.

We can fix that.

```
void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {
    char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array

    size_t len = strlen(input);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%zu\n", i);
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
    output[len] = '\0';
}
```

I don't know if this is a good fix. `strlen` is probably not safe for decrypting as it may be possible for a byte of the encrypted string to contain a null byte. It may be smarter for the function to take the length of the input.

```
void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output, size_t *strlen)

// We know baseStr is a string and can use strlen.
char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted, strlen(baseStr));

// The encrypted string is the same length as `baseStr`.
char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted, strlen(baseStr));
```

---

> ```
> output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
> ```

`(sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))` is getting the number of elements in `key`. `sizeof` produces the number of bytes. So `(sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))` produces the number of elements by dividing the size of the array by the size of each element.

`char` is always 1 byte, we can get rid of `sizeof(char)` to make things a bit simpler.

> ```
> output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % sizeof(key)];
> ```

This is doing an xor of each character of `input` with each character of `key`. Because `key` and `input` are probably different lengths, and `key` is probably shorter`, it must wrap around and reuse the` key`again.`%` is the modulus operator, it will divide and leave the remainder.

- 0 % 3 = 0
- 1 % 3 = 1
- 2 % 3 = 2
- 3 % 3 = 0
- 4 % 3 = 1

This is also referred to as "clock math".

In this way the first character of `input` is xor'd with the first character of `key`, the second with the second, the third with the third, but the fourth character of `input` is xor'd with the first character of `key`.

You can see this in action by printing `i` and the key index.

```
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%zu\n", i);
        size_t ki = i % sizeof(key);
        printf("i = %zu, ki = %zu\n", i, ki);
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[ki];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
```

`sizeof(key)/sizeof(char)` is really getting the number of elements in the list: 3/1

`I % numelemement` is gets the remainder of I/numelements  -so in this case as you go up in I position, will be 0,1,2,0,1,2 (in this case)

so

output_value = input_value XOR key[remainder]

You are not null terminating the input strings, so the strlen call is differing from the original string.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings. You can't use it for arbitrary arrays of characters. As you see, it has no way to know how many characters to print.

That code is pretty bad. It calls `strlen` on its input. So its input *must* be a C-style string. But its output is not a C-style string, it's just an array of characters. That lack of symmetry makes the code hard to use and hard to understand.